# Controllers using same function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function that two controllers will be using, and instead of both of them having the same source  code for the same function, I want it in one place and just inject the controller parameters (or perhaps the controller itself `this`). These three may exist in three separate files/modules.

```
.controller('FirstCtrl', function() {
    this.search = function(this) {
        find(this);
    };
});


.controller('SecondCtrl', function() {
    this.seek = function(this) {
        find(this);
    };
});


var find = function(controller) {
    .
    .
    .
};
```

Is this the best way? How about if I have services in my controllers like `$http` or `$scope`, and the function `find` would depend on these services? How do I inject these angular specific services to a plain JavaScript function not defined in an AngularJS module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it; one may be:

```
.factory("findMixin", function() {
    return {
        find: function() {
            // your implementation; `this` will be the controller
        }
    };
})

.controller("SomeCtrl", ["$scope", "findMixin", function($scope, findMixin) {
    angular.extend(this, findMixin);
    // here `this`, i.e. the controller, has received the methods from the mixin
    ...
})
```

The same principle (`angular.extend`) can be applied to the `$scope`, if you want `find` to be mixed into the scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a service:

```
.factory('find', [ function() {
    return function(controller, scope) {
        // ...
    };
}]);
```

And inject it into the controllers:

```
.controller('FirstCtrl', ['find', function(find) {
    this.search = function(this) {
        find(this);
    };
}]);


.controller('SecondCtrl', ['find', function(find) {
    this.seek = function(this) {
        find(this);
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks. And how about when function `find` would need a service specific to the controller, say `$scope`? How do I go about doing that?

Comment: @menorah84 You can inject the `$scope` into the service factory as well: `.factory('find', ['$scope', function($scope) { ... }]);`. I updated the answer.

Comment: as i know you can't inject $scope into a service or factory. The only scope you can inject is a $rootScope.

Comment: @MajoB Ah yes, didn't think of that. But it should be as easy as sending the current scope as an argument.